# jQuery is not Working on my WordPress Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes

I have tried everything to get my jQuery codes to work and none of it seems to work. I have checked to make sure the JavaScript script is enqueuing and loading in the browser source code and it's. I also looked at the JavaScript console for errors and no errors were found. Site is located at "http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/". The script I am loading is "init.js".

I am enqueuing the script with code bellow:

```
// Adding init file in the footer
wp_enqueue_script( 'init-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/init.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
```

Then the jQuery code that does not work is:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   if (scroll >= 50) {
     jQuery('.psad-nav-button').show()
     jQuery(".psad-nav").hide()
   }
   if (scroll < 50) {
     jQuery(".psad-nav").show()
     jQuery('.psad-nav-button').hide()
   } 
});
```

Bellow is the code that should be effected by it:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-sticky-container>
  <div data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" data-sticky-on="small" style="width:100%">
    <div class="title-bar psad-nav" data-responsive-toggle="top-bar-menu" data-hide-for="<?php echo $breakpoint ?>">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
      <div class="title-bar-title">
        <?php _e( 'Menu', 'jointswp' ); ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="top-bar psad-nav" id="top-bar-menu">
      <div class="top-bar-left show-for-<?php echo $breakpoint ?>">
        <?php do_action( 'psad_site_logo', '200px' ); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <?php joints_top_nav(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="psad-nav-button expanded button" type="button">
      ^ Navigation ^
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using foundation 6 by Zurb for Sites in my theme. The original theme is JOINTSWP. I am using the the sticky plugin to make the navigation/header to stick to the top of the page as the user scrolls down the page. I am using the ".scroll() api" to modify it with the "psad-nav" and "psad-nav-button" class. Using the ".show()" and ".hide()" api to show and hide the classes after scrolling down the page.

I have tried using other api's and nothing works on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the variable `scroll` used in the if conditions.
The value of scroll should be `document.body.scrollTop` to get the current scroll position in the document.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = document.body.scrollTop;
   if (scroll >= 50) {
     jQuery('.psad-nav-button').show()
     jQuery(".psad-nav").hide()
   }
   if (scroll < 50) {
     jQuery(".psad-nav").show()
     jQuery('.psad-nav-button').hide()
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you caught what I was missing there!

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are comparing the value of `scroll` but `scroll` is a function in the global namespace. Checking if a function is more than or less than an integer makes no sense and returns false. Your `if` statements are always false and never happen.

Comment: You should use check the hight using `scrollHeight` ex: `document.body.scrollHeight`

Comment: @Nathan K Thank you for reminding me not to use global function name for my variable name.

Comment: @Endless What is the differences between the two methods, scrollTop vs scrollHeight? Why do you suggest scrollHeight over scrollTop?

Comment: @JonasAllen.Codes The scrollHeight of an element equals to the full height of the content of it including content not visible on the screen due to overflow. The scrollTop returns the current scroll position in the document or in the given element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for their responses, I feel real smart! ;) haha You have to forgive me it's been awhile since I have been working with JavaScript. I am also surprised it didn't throw any errors in the JavaScript console. I was taking the code from a tutorial on tuts+. I didn't catch that they left out the declaration of the variable "scroll". I fixed that and it works great but then also realized I am naming a variable the same name as a global function in jQuery. I wounder if that is why it didn't throw an error for an undefined variable in the JavaScript console. I ended up changing the variable name also to avoid conflict.

Bellow is the code I ended up going with:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var psad_scroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    var psad_nav = jQuery( ".psad-nav" );
    var psad_nav_button = jQuery( ".psad-nav-button" );

    function psad_show_nav() {
        if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast( "medium" )) {
            psad_nav.show();
            psad_nav_button.addClass( "hide" ) ;
        }
    }

    function psad_hide_nav() {
        if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast( "medium" )) {
            psad_nav_button.removeClass( "hide" );
            psad_nav.hide();
        }
    }

    if (psad_scroll >= 30) {
        psad_hide_nav();
        psad_nav_button.on({
            click: psad_show_nav,
            mouseenter: psad_show_nav
        });

    }
    if (psad_scroll < 30) {
        psad_show_nav();
    }
});
```

This now works flawlessly for me, thank you all that helped me out. Would this be the best way to achieve what I was looking for? If not, how would you accomplish this?